# How to structure an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have to figure out how to present some data that is capture using gravity forms for wordpress.

There is a field for name, and attributes. Attributes contains a comma delineated list of values.

On a results page I need to display the names, followed by the top ten values. Where I'm stuck is is how to configure an array that gives me: distinct names, and within each distinct name is an array containing all values from the comma list(s).

I can't wrap my head around this to save my life. Given how GF stores enteries I think makes this especially difficult. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// A two-dimensional array:
$names = array
  (
  "sam"=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  "joe"=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  "bob"=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
  );
?>
```

Like that?

Comment: Yes. You illustrate a good example that I need one big array to hold the distinct names then an array with each etc. What's the technical name of that and how could I push to that sub array of the distinct name? I'm decent at php but I'm getting lost in so many for each loops

Comment: That is called a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks for that. In a situation like this would I use array_push or do I explicitly state the values of the array? I guess where I'm lost is adding values to the sub array of a name. If I explicitly write values to a named array will that add it to that name or create an identically named array? Please forgive me if I'm not making sense its late :)

Comment: If you use the variable "names" then when you add to it, it should continue to add not create a new one.  That is why we gave the array a label of "names".

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP but I just changed the Answer to give you better syntax, I hope. :)

Comment: Thanks Josh, sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. I'll give it a shot.